# Sparse matrix creation using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Suppose I have an Array={A,B,Y,X}. Now I do have an Excel sheet which can have dynamic number of columns and Rows.Say as an example below :

***Input:***

```
ColA   ColB   ColC  ....

 T      P      Y    ....
 C      Y      D    ....
 B      A      M    ....
 Z      R      X    ....
```

***OutPut:***

```
ColA   ColB   ColC  ....

 -      -      Y    ....
 -      Y      -    ....
 B      A      -    ....
 -      -      X    ....
```

Where all the columns will have only the Array values,if any other values are found they are required to be replaced by ***"-"***

Is there any faster process to do these using VBscript except comparatively slow looping technique?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you written the code and is it slow?  I would expect it to be pretty fast.

Comment: Yes I have using looping technique.This is an especial snapshot i have pasted here.Actual sheet has 3500 rows and 250 columns which makes it slower.Thus i am wondering for any fastest process.

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Comment: @user1878162 please post your current code in your question post. It will enable us to help you better.

Comment: @user1878162, out of curiosity: is there a particular reason for you to use VBscript and not VBA? VBA is tightly linked to the Excel spreadsheet content and it might be easier to interact with it on the level that you want here

Comment: I am not educated with VBA so much, and i was requested to implement it in VBA. I am new to VBScript also.

Comment: can you post the code for your looping solution, it might just need some tweaking to improve it.

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim arr, i, rng As Range

    arr = Array("X", "Y", "Z")
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        rng.Replace What:=arr(i), Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
Sub KeepValues()

    Dim arr, arrVals, i, rng As Range, r, c
    Dim keepval As Boolean

    arr = Array("X", "Y", "Z")

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrVals = rng.Value

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrVals, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arrVals, 2)
            keepval = False
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                If arr(i) = arrVals(r, c) Then
                    keepval = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If Not keepval Then arrVals(r, c) = ""
        Next c
    Next r

    rng.Value = arrVals

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your update,But I was looking for an equivalent VBscript code for the same.

Comment: I think your Macro will replace the Array elements from the Matrix by "-". Am I right? If I right,then would like to say you that i want the opposite you have implemented.All the elements needs to be replaced by "-", except the Array elements.

Comment: Please help me with some VBscript.. i am not familiar with VBA.

Comment: Hi Tim,Could you please help me here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843898/column-nullification-using-vbscript

Comment: Hello Tim, can you just tell me how should I change your code to do the reverse what it is now currently doing,please advise me